# some JavaScript variables missing in scope

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

The problem I am having is that I am trying to access variables that I believe should be in scope but they are not. I am using Underscore.js to loop through arrays and add up values, in the example code, within the `_.forEach` closure, I can access the `overviewRow` array but not the `overview` object. Why would one be in scope, while the other is not?

```
function(pointsReport, itemsReport, receiptsReport){
                app.stores.done(function(stores) {
                    var overview = {
                        columns: [
                            "sales",
                            "items sold",
                            "coupons redeemed",
                            "points redeemed",
                            "cost for points"
                        ],
                        rows: []
                    };

                    var overviewRow = [
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0
                    ];

                    _.forEach(itemsReport, function (item) {
                        overviewRow[0] += item.quantity * item.unitPrice;
                        overviewRow[1] += item.quantity;
                        //overview not in scope
                    });
                });
            };
```

Comment: how do you access overview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with Chrome. The developer console, when stepping through the function, could not gain access to the object. However, when I write the code in, and step through again, the object is in scope.

Welp. It's good to know that Chrome can trick you that way.